# Java: Sort a list of characters by frequency only using arrays

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I'm trying to sort a list of characters and output them by the order of frequency with their associated frequency. For example, if the user puts in "beeeerr", I want it to out put "e freq: 4, r freq: 2, b freq: 1"

Here's what I have so far:

```
public static void sort(String charInput) {
    int frequency = 0;
    char [] charArray = charInput.toCharArray();

    for (char charValue = ' '; charValue <= '~'; charValue++) {
        frequency = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < charInput.length(); i++) {
            char compare = charArray[i];
            //charInput.charAt(i)
            if (compare == charValue) {
                frequency += 1;
            }
        }
        if (frequency > 0) {
            System.out.println(charValue + " freq: " + frequency);
        }
    }

}
```

The problem with this is it outputs the frequencies in alphabetical order. I can't figure out how to sort the outputs by their frequency. I know how to easily do this with Hashmaps or Arraylists, but I'm not allowed to use them. Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

```
//128 is for ascii, change it to 256 for extended ascii
//I assume all characters in the input are in ascii or extended ascii
public void frequencySort(String s) {
    int n = s.length();
    List<Character>[]res = new ArrayList[n+1];
    int []cnt = new int[128]; 
    char []ss = s.toCharArray();
    for(int i=0;i<n;++i){
        res[i+1]=new ArrayList<>();
        cnt[ss[i]]++;
    }
    for(int i=0;i<128;++i){
        if(cnt[i]!=0){
            res[cnt[i]].add((char)i);
        }
    }

    for(int i=n;i>0;--i){
        if(!res[i].isEmpty()){
            for(char c:res[i])
            System.out.println("input has "+i+" " +c);
        }
    }
}
input has 4 e
input has 2 r
input has 1 b
```

Comment: Java uses Unicode. The question has a range of interest from ' ' to '~'. The 128 characters you refer to are the [C0 Controls and Basic Latin](http://www.unicode.org/charts/nameslist/index.html) block and the 256 add the C1 Controls and Latin-1 Supplement block. Mentioning ASCII causes confusion, and Extended ASCII—well, that's just so imprecise as to hardly  be useful. In the context of Unicode, you must have meant ISO 8859-1. Isn't is far easier to deal with String, Character and char as the [Java documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html) describes?

Comment: Thanks for your correction.  For this problem, you can just change 128 to the number of characters in unicode set.

Answer (score 0):

With Java 8 Stream API, you can usually perform such operations with one liners:

```
    str.chars().mapToObj(e->(char)e).collect(Collectors.toSet()).stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(ch -> ch, ch -> str.length() - str.replaceAll(ch.toString(), "").length()))
        .entrySet().stream().sorted(Collections.reverseOrder(Map.Entry.comparingByValue()))
        .forEach(e -> System.out.println(e.getKey() + " freq: " + e.getValue()));
```